# How can I pair my Apple Magic keyboard to my mac without USB Cable?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

AFAIK you have to pair using a usb cable, but my macbook has only USB-C cable and I don't have the adapter with me.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: In my answer I mentioned you can use Bluetooth but I also mentioned you can rename the device to make sure it’s yours

Comment: no problem, if my answer helped feel free to press the taco next to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a compatible device you can connect it using Bluetooth in System Preferences -> Bluetooth.

**If you haven’t set up your devices:**

> Connect a Lightning to USB Cable1 or  a USB-C to Lightning Cable to
>   the  Lightning port on the device2 and  connect the other end of the
>   cable to  your Mac.
>
> Make sure that the device's power  switch is in the ON position.
>   (Green is  visible under the switch when the  device is on.)
>
> Choose Apple () menu > System  Preferences, then click Bluetooth to 
>   open the Bluetooth preferences  window. When the device pairs with 
>   your Mac, it appears in the list of  devices.
>
> Check the Bluetooth preferences  window to see your device's charge 
>   level. When the device is charged,  unplug it for wireless use.

This does not require a USB cable.

To avoid connecting another persons keyboard you can rename yours. To do this control-click the keyboard and click rename:

[image]

Then you can change the keyboard name.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Even though the answer says that the quoted procedure does not require a USB cable it starts by saying "Connect a Lightning to USB cable..."

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this was because of lower battery or just that it needed to be plugged in, but simply by connecting a charger (from the wall) to my keyboard and then going to MacBook's Bluetooth I was able to connect/pair it. 
This makes me wonder how you can avoid accidentally pairing another person's keyboard or potentially highjacking a few of keyboard strokes...

[image]

**Credits:** https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/6z3u9k/is_there_a_way_to_pair_a_magic_mouse_without/dmsa4jk